# The convergence of $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ in the discrete topology of $\mathbf{R}$

Tags: general-topology

I am asked to find and prove the point to which $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ converges in the discrete topology of $\mathbf{R}$. I know the definition of sequence convergence in topology, yet I am still stuck in figuring out the solution. May anyone help?

Comment: The sequence does not converge in the discrete topology. Only sequences that are eventually constant converge in a discrete topology. You are being asked to find something that does not exist, and then prove something which is false.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Before your comment I worked that out, here is my solution: $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ does not converge in discrete topology, since when we assume $x_n$ converges to a specific point $x$ of $\mathbf{R}$, we can always construct a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ that does not contain any point of the form $\frac{1}{n},n\in\mathbf{N}$. In that neighbourhood, $x_n\notin U$ for all $n$.

Comment: A little quicker is to note that for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$, the set $\{x\}$ is an open neighborhood of $x$. If $x_n$ converges to $x$, then there exists $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$, $x_n\in\{x\}$. Thus, the sequence must be eventually constant.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you, your idea is much better.